# How to add multiple property into a List of IEnumerable<Student>

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I have created a class `Student` and in the class it has those properties:

```
      class Student: IEnumerable<Student>
    {
    private int age =0 ;
    private string name ="";
    private bool isAdult = false;


List<Student> StudentList = new List<Student>();

        public Student this[int index]
        {
            get { return StudentList [index]; }
            set { StudentList .Insert(index, value); }
        }

        public IEnumerator<Student> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return StudentList.GetEnumerator();
        }

        System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return this.GetEnumerator();
        }


    public string Name 
            {
                get { return name ; }
                set { name = value; }
            } 

    public int Age 
            {
                get { return age ; }
                set { age = value; }
            } 
    public bool IsAdult 
            {
                get { return isAdult ; }
                set { isAdult = value; }
            } 

    }
```

Now what I want to do , is to load the result of an oracle query in a new list of student

```
//...
try

List < Student > StudentList = new List < Student > (); {

    OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(sqlQuery, connection);
    OracleDataReader oracleDataReader = command.ExecuteReader();
    while (oracleDataReader.Read()) {

        age = Convert.Int64(oracleDataReader["age"]);
        name = oracleDataReader["name"].toString();
        isAdult = Convert.boolean(oracleDataReader["isAdult"])
    }
}
//...
```

Let's say the query returns 100 students and the student class actually contains 10-15 properties, I only took 3 ( name , age , isAdult ) as an example to explain my issue

Would it be possible to load inside the `StudentList` every returned row from the query ?

Comment: Attributes? I don't see an attribute.

Comment: @RandRandom Sorry , Attributes means property , We have a little language difference in my country , we call the properties attributes, I have edited the question to match the multinational English .

Comment: Btw, you should re-evaluate the 'age' column in your database it's wiser to store the birthday and calculate the age based on that.

Comment: @RandRandom There is no column called 'age' I simply used dummy column name just to explain my objective . Thank you for the information and suggestion

Comment: What are `Convert.Int64`, `Convert.boolean` and `toString`?

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 I convert the database result to the corresponded types otherwise an error will be triggered

Comment: You missed the point. The methods are `Convert.ToInt64`, `Convert.ToBoolean` and `ToString`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is that your `Student` class tries to implement the `IEnumerable<Student>` interface. That doesn't make sense. The `IEnumerable<Student>` interface should be implemented by some other class. Or you use the `List<...>` class, which implements this interface. The `Student` class should only contain the values you want to save about a student.

Assuming you have just a `List<Student>` object somewhere at the while loop, you can just iterate over the rows from your database, create a new `Student` object and add it to the list.

```
IList<Student> students = new List<Student>();
while (oracleDataReader.Read()) {

    int age = Convert.Int64(oracleDataReader["age"]);
    string name = oracleDataReader["name"].toString();
    bool isAdult = Convert.boolean(oracleDataReader["isAdult"]);

    Student student = new Student {
        age = age,
        name = name,
        isAdult = isAdult
    };
    students.Add(student);
}
```

Then you can work with your `students` list.

Comment: Make much more sense , I used `IEnumerable<Student>` as a way to replace a `DataTable` because I heard IEnumerable is much better